# After EntityManager remove object found during synchronization

Tags: java, jpa, cascade, entitymanager, toplink

I am trying to remove an Entity that has a one-to-many relationship with another entity, with an Application managed EntityManager. The object seems to be removed just fine but then when another transaction is opened and then committed I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.RollbackException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: RemovedParentObject[id=1].
```

My Entities have the following relationship annotation.

In the Parent class

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parentId")
private List<Child> childCollection;
```

In the child class

```
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Parents parentId;
```

My remove Code is,

```
 // start database transaction window
 EntityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    // remove all children
    for (Child child: parent.getChildCollection())
    {
        EntityManager.remove(child);
    }

    parent.getChildCollection().clear();

    // remove parent
    EntityManager.remove(parent);

// commit chages to the database
EntityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

I have tried removing only the children in one transaction, committing it, opening another one and removing the parent and then committing. No change, error occurs.

I have also tried not removing the children, only removing the parent since it has a cascade.ALL annotation. No change, error occurs.

I have tried refreshing all parents and children after removal. the refreshed list does not show the removed parent, but when i next call commit the error occurs.

The parent and each child is managed when this code is called. I am assuming that the remove process is incorrect and that is why the removed object is found when the future commit is executed.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Shouldn't it be all done in one transaction? From my bare understanding, each entity manager links to a transaction, and each entity links to its corresponding entity manager. It is considered invalid if you are using an entity on another entity manager.

Comment: @Adrian Shum, I believe that the above code has the removal all in one transaction, if not please let me know where another transaction is being started. I am using the same Entitymanager to start and end the transaction as well as the same EntityManager to remove the children and then the parent. At least that is what I believe I am doing in the above code. I did say that I tried two transactions but that did not change the error.

Comment: oh probably I misunderstood what you mean as I thought that what you are doing is "removing child in one transaction and remove parent in another".  Then I am not that clear what your question is, as in your first sentence in question, you said "when another transaction is opened and then committed"

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying. After the code above is executed, i.e. the parent and child are removed, I have to start another transaction to make a change to another object in my database. When I am trying to commit that change to the other non parent or child object, after of the removal process, it is then that I get this error. I presented the removal code because the error references the parent that I thought was removed by the code above.

Comment: Instead of starting another transaction, have you tried to get a new EntityManager from the entity manager factory for your 2nd sets of actions?

Comment: If your JPA provider implements JPA2, you may be able to add orphanRemoval=true to the @OneToMany, then inside the transaction, only have to do EntityManager.remove(parent);

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that no other existing objects are referencing the object you removed.  Ensure you are not merging an object that references the deleted object.  Are you sure the error is complaining about the deleted object?

Do you create a new EntityManager or use the existing one?  Does it work if you create a new one?  If you just begin and commit the next transaction without doing anything, does it work?

You could try disabling the shared cache, to see if that affects it.

Also check that the commit is successful, and does not throw an error.

Also try using the latest release.

Comment: After looking into this, I determined that the second transaction occurred with a different reference to my Entity Manager. This problem only occurred using this different reference and not when I performed other transactions with the same entity manager or different Entity Managers after the remove.